# Отлов события удаления приложения

Tags: android

Возможно ли перед удалением приложения как-то отлавливать событие удаления и показать пользователю диалог/activity, а затем продолжить удаление.
Пробовал код [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/1360579), но похоже на 4.0, и выше решение нерабочее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подробно [изложено на Стэке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692571/how-it-works-warning-that-app-is-going-to-be-uninstalled) - сам лично задавал такой вопрос